# Hibernate+Postgres: Relation doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I'm trying to execute a simple SQL query using Hibernate with Postgres.

```
insert into node_user (USER_EMAIL, USER_NAME, USER_PUBLIC_KEY_BASE64, USER_ID) values ($1, $2, $3, $4)
```

But Hibernate says

`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "node_user" does not exist`

I don't know what to do. This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
node-postgres:
    image: postgres:9.5
    container_name: node-postgres
    ports:
      - 15432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
      POSTGRES_USER: test
    volumes:
      - ../init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    networks:
      - node-project
```

This is my `init.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE node_user(
    USER_ID VARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY,
    USER_NAME VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    USER_EMAIL VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    USER_PUBLIC_KEY_BASE64 VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
```

This is my `SessionFactory`:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
            properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.postgresql.Driver");
            properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:postgresql://" + masterServerConfig.getDbConfig().getHost() + ":" + masterServerConfig.getDbConfig().getPort() + "/postgres");
            properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", "test");
            properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", "test");
            properties.put("show_sql", "true");
            properties.put("format_sql", "true");
            properties.put(Environment.C3P0_MIN_SIZE, 5);
            properties.put(Environment.C3P0_MAX_SIZE, 20);
            properties.put(Environment.C3P0_TIMEOUT, 1800);
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
            configuration.setProperties(properties);
```

And this is my `Entity` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "node_user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6569577055168857214L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "USER_PUBLIC_KEY_BASE64")
    private String publicKeyBase64;
    @Column(name = "USER_EMAIL")
    private String email;
```

I can clearly see the table in the logs if I connect to the DB:

```
root@e784895a1f3c:/# psql -U test
psql (9.5.20)
Type "help" for help.

test=# \dt
       List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  | Owner
--------+------+-------+-------
 public | node_user | table | test
```

I'm out of any ideas. What is wrong?

Comment: Where is your query? Are you using nativeQuery? If not, you have to still point to `User` in your query

Comment: I have posted a query made by Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question if you are using native query or not. If you are then you need to add the schema name in front of the table name. You could hard-code it, but a better approach is to use [`{h-schema}`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-resolve-the-hibernate-global-database-schema-and-catalog-for-native-sql-queries/).